# Jquery UI dialog does not disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp

I am using jquery-ui tabs and dialog functionality.

Each tab has a button on the page which opens a dialog. This works for one of the tabs. However if I go the second tab, the button does not work there. When I come back to the first tab, the dialog does show up but the problem is I notice as I make switches back and forth to the first tab, it keeps on inserting new div's while the old div's have display:none set on them.

I am doing this using JSP. This is how the reusable jsp looks like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var formData = null;
    $.ajax({
        url : "addFormGenerator.html",
        success : function(data) {
            formData = data;
            $("#addFormDialog").html(data);
            $("#addFormDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                height : 300,
                width : 350,
                modal : true,
                buttons : {
                    "Add" : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close : function() {
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#addButton").button().click(function() {
        $("#addFormDialog").html(formData);
        $("#addFormDialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>

<button id="addButton">Click here to Add New</button>
<div id="addFormDialog" title="Add New"></div>
```

This jsp fragment is included in other jsp pages as well.
I was assuming as I switch between tabs the old button will be garbage collected.

Can you help me understand the problem and fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not render the following part from your jsp's response

```
<div class="addFormDialog" title="Add New"></div>

$("#addButton").button().click(function() {
        $("#addFormDialog").html(formData);
        $("#addFormDialog").dialog("open");
});
```

---

Just have the following, ideally with class names and not duplicate id's

```
<button class="addButton">Click here to Add New</button>
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I still don't think you need unique id's -

```
<div id="tabs-container">

    <!-- tabs here -- >

    <-- let's say this is tab#1 -->
       <button class="addButton">Click here to Add New</button>
       <div class="addFormDialog" title="Add New"></div>
    <!-- tab1 -->
</div>


$('#tabs-container').on('click' , '.addButton', function(){
    var dialogContent = $(this).siblings('.addFormDialog');
    //now call .dialog({..});  or whatever you need
});
```

This way you're binding just one click handler that listens to any `click` that bubbles up from a `.addButton` and then searches for its sibling `.addFormDialog`. (I hope I'm not sounding too confusing)

Comment: Thanks Robin... What you say makes sense ...
Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a7x4T/14/

However now all three dialogs show up (expected) at the same time.
I was having same ids so that I could reuse the jsp page anywhere I want.

Comment: This is what I ultimately want:
http://jsfiddle.net/a7x4T/18/

So I guess I should be looking for a convenient way to generate unique ids in JSP and passing them to javascript somehow. If you know of a way then can you please tell me. Basically this jsp fragment needs to be reusable so anyone can include it and expect the button to work.
Thanks a lot Robin!

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: Yes :) Generating unique id's would solve the problem. You could the HTTP Session ID for that. However, I have updated my answer with yet another approach.

Comment: For now I fixed this issue with different ids. But hit another annoying problem http://bit.ly/NjmHuQ
Anyways thanks a ton!